# GSM Operator Register problem (CREG:3 Error)

Tags: gsm, sim

I am using Turkcell operator (2G) in my application (**28601**). GSM Modem: Telit / GE910QUAD. I use the AT sequence listed below:

```
AT
AT&F0
ATE0
AT+CMEE=1
AT+FCLASS=0
AT&K0
AT+CPIN?
AT+CGSN
AT+GSN
AT#CCID
AT+GMI
AT+GMM
AT+GMR
AT#SLED=2
AT#E2SLRI=50
AT#TXMONMODE=1
AT#AUTOBND=1
AT+COPS=0,2,28601
AT+CREG=0
```

And then I query CREG with

```
AT+CREG?
```

After a few (searching) responses, it then returns the **CREG=3** answer.

Then I query the error with AT#CEER. The command returns Ceer:31. After that, I query the operator via AT#MONIZIP.

The module says: "connected to **28602** (Vodafone) operator". (my SIM is a 28601-Turkcell SIM).

Why does this happen?

Comment: first possibility: roaming: your modem does not get (sufficient) connectivity to turkcell's network, and automatically roams to the vodafone network that in your location has better reception. This can be 100% transparent (and cost-free to you), or not. Depends on how that is regulated. Second possibility: your modem needs to be explicitly told that it should use a specific network mode; `AT+WS46=12` would enforce GSM only, which would imply circuit-switched data (horribly inefficient; it's possible turkcell just turned that off).

Comment: Assuming this is a low-power application, you'd want `AT+WS46=39` instead, is my guess: 5G, 4G or EDGE (which people slightly confusingly call "2.5G"); you really don't want pure 2G for a data device.

Comment: **So**: first thing to check whether your device actually does get turkcell connectivity. It simply might not – wrong antenna for the bands that are used, or simply hardware not able to use these, or simply bad location. Maybe also your SIM card isn't allowed to connect! (subscription needs to be externally activated first, or subscription simply not valid) The fact that you get "searching" statuses really suggests you simply *can't* connect to turkcell's infrastructure.

Comment: i control the parameter list by "AT+WS46=?" but modem allows only 12 for WS46 command. And I try it but nothing changed. :(

Comment: Then, as said, check whether your operator actually offers pure, non-EDGE, 2G in your location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the network has taken down GSM and would only respond to CGREG or CEREG instead of CREG:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71207864/2103990